# loadKeyMaterial method deprecated, tell me the alternative

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

```
configureBody(request, requestData.getBody())
            configureHeaders(request, requestData.getHeadersAsMap())
            String keyPassphrase = "password";

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("Resources/certificates/selfsigned.jks"), keyPassphrase.toCharArray());


            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password").build(); //(keyStore, "password").build()

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();


            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, httpClientContext)

coming error:- groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial()
```

i am using httpclient4.5.5 jar. loadkeyMaterial method was deprecated in httpclient4.4. kindly suggest some alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [loadKeyMaterial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadKeyMaterial(java.io.File,%20char[],%20char[])) from `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` instead fo from `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` which is deprecated.

So, basically change your imports:

```
// The one deprecated to be removed from your code
//import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
// The good one
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
```

Comment: import java.security.KeyStore
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder
class HttpclientRequest {
void loadcer(){
String keyPassphrase = "password";
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("Resources/certificates/selfsigned.jks"), keyPassphrase.toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password").build();

Comment: HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
}
}